# Generating two dimensional array between min and max number using D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3.js so please bear with me. The below image shows what I am trying to draw and it was created in Excel. It has this beautiful curve for each object.

[image]

I get this smooth line based on this formula. I will get parameters for Alpha ,Beta and max for X and based on that I have to find y using the formula below ->   y=Alpha(1-2.71828*(-Beta*x)) and x has to be a number generated from min 100 to spent amount by incrementing by 100.

In Excel I can just generate the number for X like this and find y for each

```
100     1.28E-01
200     0.256638873
300     0.384674585
400     0.51252152
500     0.640179956
600     0.76765017
700     0.894932441
800     1.022027046
900     1.14893426
1,000   1.275654361
1,100   1.402187624
1,200   1.528534325
```

but in JS base on the below, how to generate X which should increment by 100 between 0 to the spent amount and it should create two dimensional array in order to provide for X, Y for each object. For example, if min is 0 and max is 20000, how to generate array between min and max which increments at 100?

How to calculate Y based on generated X? Can you please give me some guidance in order to create this two dimensional array to draw this line using D3.js?

```
name    alpha        beta       max_x_val   spend
BAN1    140.3       3.86E-05    28,675.00   29,919.00
BAN2    115.31      2.08E-05    32,302.00   28,367.00
BAN3    5.07E-05    19,740.00   16,972.00
ADJ4    91.8        0.000029119 25,855.00   27,112.00
ADJ5    90.3        2.81E-05    25,793.00   23,883.00
```

I can draw the line using below code which works great, only if I can create two dimensional array for each object.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var bezierLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .interpolate("basis");

var svg = d3.select("#bezier-demo")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 150);

svg.append('path')
    .attr("d", bezierLine([ [0.1, 0.13], [0.2, 0.26], [0.3, 0.38], [0.4, 0.51], [0.5, 0.64], [0.6, 0.77]]))
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
            var len = this.getTotalLength();
            return function(t) { return (d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0"))(t) };
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [d3.range()](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#range) function. It produces an arithmetic progression, and with a simple `.map()` you can enhance that to a two-dimensional array:

```
var lineData = d3.range(0, spend, 100)
     .map(x => [ x, alpha * (1 - 2.71828 * (-beta * x))] );
```